# Ldap Parital string search on address attrbiute that contains $

Tags: directory, ldap

I am trying to search out a list of addresses by the postcode using a partial match but it doesn't work.

The attribute I am searching is a string. When I search for the attribute with just * I get a list of all the records in the catalog with an address.

When I tried to search on a part of the address, e.g *444 31* it doesn't find any matches.

When I look at existing addresses they are formatted with a $

e.g

Backa Läkarhusgruppen Stenungsund$ $Strandvägen 23D$ $444 31$Stenungsund

When I double click then in the Apache Studio the address is formatted like so

Backa Läkarhusgruppen Stenungsund

Strandvägen 23D

444 31
Stenungsund

With the $ becoming a line break.

How can i search partially on this attribute?

Answer (score 0):

How about using Substring match ?

```
(address=*444 31*) or (address=*$444 31$*)
```

Regards,

Ludovic

Answer (score 0):

Substring matches with * before and after the string to search doesn't work. That is the problem.